# How to parse a table from an saved HTLM page?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can you parse the data from a table on a saved HTML page (the HTML page is saved to the same folder as this script) via python? This code pulls all of the pertinent data from the page, but how can I get it to be formatted in a table structure using python to then export to CSV?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("Sysco Online Order Confirmation (2).html"),"html.parser")

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    print(table)
```

Comment: if you do just `open(...)` what do you get back?

Comment: As in running the file with the 'for' and 'print' lines commented out? That does nothing on its own.

Comment: use `print(open(...))` and see what it says

Comment: I would use pandas and [read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) once you have the actual html to draw from

Comment: @SuperStew That prints this: _io.TextIOWrapper name='Sysco Online Order Confirmation (2).html' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> html.parser followed by a traceback error

Comment: @G.Anderson, by that, do you mean using the results of this script to then use pandas to read it? Or do you mean when I have the live HTML via a webpage to draw from?

Comment: right. so you need to read the file, not just open it. bs4 doesn't parse through the text wrapper object

Comment: Is that what @G.Anderson is recommending? Pull out the raw HTML then use pandas to read it?

Comment: you don't *have* to use pandas, but yes essentially. I think pandas may do the opening/reading/closing for you so it would be simpler code.

Comment: Thanks, folks. I was able to get it done using this 'import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_html
import html5lib
import lxml

url = "Sysco Online Order Confirmation (2).html"

data = pd.read_html(url)

df = data[1]

print(df.info())

df.to_csv('file1.csv')
'